# Pressing a key will spawn a lot of screens

Tags: c#, xna

I have the code below:

```
        else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.E)) // if the 'E' key is pressed
        {
            form = new InventoryScreen();         //define winform instance
            form.Show();                          //display winform
        }
```

It works, maybe too well. Because when the user presses and holds the 'E' key, the program generates **a lot** of winform screens. Is there a way to instruct the program to only run the following only once? Also, how would I write it so that if I press the 'E' key again, the window will disapear?

Comment: It looks like form is defined before the conditional branch so you could do something like `else if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.E) && (form == null || !form.Visible))`

Comment: Once per click, or once per session?  Or once per key press?

Comment: @KennyThompson When i press the 'E' key, the code runs once, that's my goal

Comment: What event are you handling?  Is it keypress or keydown?

Comment: @KennyThompson press means keydown...i think. Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: @AlphaDelta tried it, still generated an insane amount of screens

Comment: Keypress and keydown are two separate events.  See the answer below.

Comment: You can use keyup** or do some alternate logic.  Here is another question on SO similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251522/ensure-statement-is-executed-only-once-when-a-key-is-pressed-and-held

Comment: @KennyThompson thank you for finding that post, it solved my problem

Comment: You should accept his answer then. Also, make sure you properly dispose of the child form you're creating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a separate event handler firing on `keyup`.  Within the handler you can check to see if the key is indeed 'E'.  The keyup event will only fire once when the key is pressed and not fire while the key is held down.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The code given in the question uses XNA functions. XNA has no KeyUp or KeyDown events. While I think there is a way to combine an XNA Game class with a Windows Form, it is not a good way to go.

Comment: I see.  I guess I assumed he was talking about a windows form when he said "the program generates a lot of winform screens".  I do see that the above code is in XNA, but he is at least using winforms to an extent.

Answer (score 0):

XNA is not event-driven, it is instead a game loop.

There is no built-in event that fires on keys being press or not. One option is to only handle the 'E' event if no form is created.

A second option is to keep the old keyboard state, like this:

```
KeyboardState oldState;
```

Update(..):

```
KeyboardState now = Keyboard.GetState();
if (now.IsKeyUp(Keys.E) && oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.E))
// i.e. a "release event"
{
  form.Show();
}
oldState = now;
```

For the variant with disappearing, this might work or something similar, but you should probably instead handle it in the created form:

```
KeyboardState now = Keyboard.GetState();
if (now.IsKeyUp(Keys.E) && oldState.IsKeyDown(Keys.E))
// i.e. a "release event"
{
  if (form.Visible)
  {
   form.Hide();
  } 
 else 
{
  form.Show();
}
```

}
    oldState = now;